# Prove by induction that $\forall n \in\mathbb N$, $3\mid4^{n}-1$.

Tags: induction, divisibility

Prove by induction that $\forall n \in\mathbb N$, $3\mid4^{n}-1$.

1) For $n = 1$ the statement is obviously true.

2) Now what about $n+1$? I was thinking of writing $4^{n}-1$ as $2^{2n}-1$ and then $4^{n+1}-1 = 2^{2n+2}-1$ but that got me nowhere.

Comment: Instead of complicating things by writing $4^n=2^{2n}$, why not instead write $4^{n+1}-1$ in terms of $4^n-1$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I tried, but failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $\;4^{n+1}-1=4 \cdot 4^n-1=(3+1)\cdot 4^n-1=3\cdot 4^n + 4^n-1\,$.

The non-induction proofs are more direct, though:

- $\;4^n-1 =(4-1)(4^{n-1}+4^{n-2}+\ldots+1)$
- $\;4^n-1=(3+1)^n - 1 = \ldots$

Comment: So simple, thanks.

Comment: @lmc When you don't "see" it right away, try to force it: $\,4^{n+1}-1=\underbrace{4^{n+1}\color{red}{-4^n}}_{4^n\,\cdot\, (4-1)}\,\underbrace{\color{red}{+4^n}-1}_{\text{multiple of }3}\,$.

Comment: Why was this question posed?  In general $x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+1)$ is divisible by $x-1$ directly, without induction.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I am not the one to answer that question. The non-inductive proofs are indeed simpler, as noted above.